# Fitting Inspection Time Data to Curve

Tags: curve-fitting, logistic-curve

I have a set of Inspection Time data that consists of two variables: SOA (stimulus onset asynchrony) and Accuracy.  This data refers to how accurately you can perform on a simple stimuli discrimination task at a given duration of exposure.  The accuracy data is binary (0,1) and the SOA data is in increments of .01 (10 milliseconds).

```
SOA = [.01, .02, .02, .03, .02, .01.....]
Accuracy = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1.....]
```

What I need to do is estimate the SOA at 75% accuracy.  I've been told that this is done by fitting the data to a curve (y-axis accuracy, x-axis SOA) and then taking the SOA value at 75%.  Unfortunately I have mixed information about what kind of curve to use: sigmoid, gauss, logistic, and cumulative normal curve.

So far I've managed to fit a binary logistic curve to the data using R, but there seems to be no method of estimating SOA at 75% accuracy.  Could someone please suggest a method for accomplishing my task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you fit a 'binary logistic curve', what's the actual model?

Comment: Admittedly I'm not sure what you mean by your question, as I've had fairly little contact with statistics until recently.  I ran a logistic regression model (generalized linear model with logit link) with accuracy as my dependent variable and SOA as my independent variable.

Comment: Thanks; that tells me enough to work out what the model probably was. This is essentially an inverse (logistic) regression problem. There are ways to approach this, but it's not something I am especially knowledgeable about.